# Use Lagrange multipliers to find the extrema of F subject to $ x + y + z = 25, \space F(x,y,z) = x^2 + y^2 + z^2$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

Here is what I have so far: $$\nabla F(x,y,z) = \lambda \nabla G(x,y,z)$$
$$(2x)i + (2y)j + (2z)k = \lambda(i + j + k) $$
$$\left\{ \begin{array}{l}
2x = \lambda \\[1ex]
2y = \lambda \\[1ex]
2z = \lambda \\[1ex]   \end{array} \right.$$
How can I use this to find the extrema ?

Comment: Then your fourth equation is $x+y+z=25$, so four equations four unknowns you know the rest

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$x=y=z=\lambda/2$. Substituting into $x+y+z=25$, we get
$$\frac{3}{2}\lambda=25$$
so $\lambda = 50/3$ and at the extrema, $(x,y,z)=(25/3,25/3,25/3)$ and 
$$F(x,y,z)=3\left(\frac{25}{3}\right)^2=\frac{625}{3}.$$